# Unable to access Kafka Broker from separate LAN machine

Tags: networking, apache-kafka

EDIT: OBE - figured it out. Provided in answer for anyone else who has this issue.

I am working in an offline environment and am unable to connect to a kafka broker, on machine 1, from a separate machine, machine 2, on a LAN connection through a single switch.

Machine 1 (where Kafka and ZK are running):

```
server.properties
listeners=PLAINTEXT://<ethernet_IPv4_m1>:9092
advertised.listeners=PLAINTEXT://<ethernet_IPv4_m1>:9092
zookeeper.connect=localhost:2181
```

I am starting kafka/ZK from the config files located in `kafka_2.12-2.8.0/config` and the running the appropritate `.bat` from `kafka_2.12-2.8.0/bin/windows`.

On machine 2 I am able to `ping <ethernet_IPv4_m1>` and get results; however, I fail to get a TCP connection if I run `Test-NetConnection <ethernet_IPv4_m1> -p 9092` while kafka is running. In python 3.8.11, using KafkaConsumer from kafka-python, I receive the `NoBrokersAvailable` error when using <ethernet_IPv4_m1>:9092 as the `bootstrap_server`. Additionally if I run a python:3.8.12-buster docker container with a `'/bin/bash'` entrypoint, and follow along with the [kafka-listener](https://www.confluent.io/blog/kafka-client-cannot-connect-to-broker-on-aws-on-docker-etc/) walkthrough I am unable to connect to the broker. I'm in the exact situation as Scenario 1 provided in the link, but the walkthrough assumes you can connect to the broker. I have also tried opening the 9092 port in my Windows Defender for in/outbound traffic (on both machines) and still have no luck. Neither Kafka, nor networking, are my strong suits and every tutorial/answer I find refers to changing the `listener` and `advertised.listener` in the kafka `server.properties` file - I think I correctly did this, but am unsure. This is everything I have tried so far, any recommendations would be greatly appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For M1, the private network was the active network.

Go to control panel -> Firewall & network protection -> advanced settings (must be admin) -> setup inbound/outbound rules for port 9092 for the active network.